# Multiple conditions are true in If statement (Nefted If)

Tags: if-statement, plsql, conditional-statements, oracle12c, nested-if

I have a nested if condition :

```
If (a > 0)
THEN 
  Delete from sample_table where id = 123;
   
    IF (b > 0)
       dummy = error_insert('x','y','The value of b is greater than 0',0);
     commit;
     Return;
     END IF;
END IF;
```

So I wanted to check if the variable a has greater than 0 and if so it should delete the value from sample_table and then check if the variable b has greater value than 0 and insert the values as mentioned.

But what it actually does it that checks if a is greater than 0 and directly goes to checking if b is greater than 0. It doesnt perform the delete statement.

Comment: That's hard to believe. DELETE won't do anything only if there are no rows in SAMPLE_TABLE whose ID = 123. If you disagree, please, post test case which illustrates what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the whole code so all I can do is guessing.

There can be 2 reason why code didn't work as you've expected.

First and the easiest, as mentioned by @littlefoot, there are no lines to delete.

It is easy to check and I believe you've already done that and still wondering why records are still there in the database. So here goes the second guess.

Second, it is the postition of "commit" command in your code. The program you have will commit ONLY if a > 0 and b > 0. So, my guess is in your test case "a" is greater than 0 and "b" is not greater than 0 and commit command can't be reached.